# How to set marker on center of the map?

Tags: java, android, center, android-mapview, marker

I want to use a map view in my app which will show the markers position when we drag the map. For that I have got that it can be done by setting the marker at the center of the map so when we drag the map we can get the address of the current position. Like this : [image]

But I don't know how to achieve this. Hope I will get help from here.

ChooseFromMapActivity

```
public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {

    TextView textShowAddress;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng latLng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);

        latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        textShowAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
  }
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions()
                        .position( position.target )
                        .title( position.toString() )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the map according to your marker position as:

```
latLang = marker.getPosition(); // get LatLang object
map.setCenter(latLang); //set google maps instance with that object of LatLang
```

You can also try the another method by moving the camera position as:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom));
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Its showing error on setCenter. can not resolve method setCenter.

Comment: Its giving error for latitude and longitude. I have initialized the variables. Don't know whats going wrong. Can you please show me code in detail??

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 16));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(location)
        .draggable(false)
        .title("sent location :)"));
```

Comment: Thank you for reply... I dint understand location variable is for what?? Is it a Latlang variable?

Comment: This just moves camera to the location. It dosen't give the drag effect to the marker as I want.

Comment: @user3623979 yes, it is a latlng variable

Comment: Yes i have tried this code but it id not showing any results when the map is draged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) 
{
    if(mMarker==null)
    {
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cameraPosition.target).title("Marker in Sydney")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.marker_ico)));
        mMarker.showInfoWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        mMarker.setPosition(cameraPosition.target);
    }
}
});
```

The only problem is that your marker will move to centre of the map only at the end of map dragging. You can just add ImageView and paste it at the centre of your map Fragment to avoid this problem. After that you can use mMarker.setVisible(false); to hide your marker and showing only ImageView as your marker.